# So, what exactly is the deal with QSharedMemory on application crash?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, shared-memory

When a Qt application that uses QSharedMemory crashes, some memory handles are left stuck in the system.
The "recommended" way to get rid of them is to

```
if(memory.attach(QSharedMemory::ReadWrite))
    memory.detach();
bool created = memory.create(dataSize, QSharedMemory::ReadWrite);
```

In theory the above code should work like this:

We attach to a left over piece of sh...ared memory, detach from it, it detects that we are the last living user and gracefully goes down.

Except... that is not what happens in a lot of cases. What I actually see happening, a lot, is this:

```
// fails with memory.error() =  SharedMemoryError::NotFound
memory.attach(QSharedMemory::ReadWrite);
// fails with "segment already exists" .. wait, what?! (see above)
bool created = memory.create(dataSize, QSharedMemory::ReadWrite);
```

The only somewhat working way I've found for me to work around this is to write a pid file on application startup containing the pid of the currently running app.
The next time the same app is run it picks up this file and does

```
//QProcess::make sure that PID is not reused by another app at the moment
//the output of the command below should be empty
ps -p $previouspid -o comm=
//QProcess::(runs this script, reads output)
ipcs -m  -p | grep $user | grep $previouspid | sed "s/  / /g" | cut -f1 -d " "
//QProcess::(passes the result of the previous script to clean up stuff)
ipcrm -m $1
```

Now, I can see the problems with such approach myself, but it is *the only thing that works*

The question is: can someone explain to me what exactly is the deal with not so not existing memory in the first piece of code above and how to deal with it properly?

Comment: No real Answer but a theory: You see this effect only sporadically after a random crash of a multithreaded program ? Here's my theory: On destroying the QSharedMemory Qt needs to release both a shared memory segment and an associated semaphore. Sometimes it crashes after releasing the semaphore but before the shared mem can be released. If you try to create a new one Qt finds the dangling shared mem and tells you it already exists. If you try to attach it fails since it fails to find the semaphore.

Comment: I think I don't have any threads in at least one of my apps that can break this way.